# Python: multiplying columns of sparse matrix by scalar returns out-of-bounds error

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, scalar

Given a `100x180` sparse matrix `U` of `0` and `1` which looks like this:

```
In[1]: U.todense()
Out[1]:
matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        ..., 
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

And a method (from NetworkX) with 180 scalar values which looks like this:

```
In[2]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[2]: 
[(0, 1, 1.0),
 (0, 10, 1.0),
 (1, 11, 1.0),
 (1, 2, 1.0),
 (2, 3, 1.0),... ]
```

I want to multiply each column in the matrix by the third element of the corresponding tuple in `G.edges()` (trivial case here: all values are `1.0`), so what I do is:

```
U.todense() #U.shape[0]=100 (rows); U.shape[1]=180 (columns)
W=U
W.todense()

for j in range(0, U.shape[1]):
    W[:][j]=U[:][j]*G.edges(data=True)[j][2]
```

**What am I missing, given that I receive this error?**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-3a2b00447c19> in <module>()
     21 
     22 for j in range(0, U.shape[1]):
---> 23     W[:][j]=U[:][j]*G.edges(data=True)[j][2]
     24 

    ...
    ...
    ...
IndexError: index out of bounds: 0 <= 100 <= 100, 0 <= 101 <= 100, 100 <= 101
```

Comment: What is the value produced by print U.shape[1]? j going out of bounds would imply that U.shape[1] is out of bounds for the matrices in question.

Comment: right. So maybe you want to use U.shape[0] instead?

Comment: `U.shape[0]=100`, and this won't match `len(G.edges(data=True))`, which is 180.

Comment: Well, it looks to me like the error indicates that one of your lists ends at 100, not 180. Is it U[:], or W[:]? If len(G.edges(data=True)) == 180, it's not G.edges(data=True).

Comment: None of them, interestingly. They all have 180 elements.

Comment: But my `j` stops at `100` instead of `180`...

Comment: Well, that's odd. I don't know what else to suggest...